# Bochner's Theorem for Periodic Function of Two Variables

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am not experienced with measure theory, so I am struggling to apply Bochner's theorem to a function of two variables in my research. From my understanding (please correct if I'm wrong), a Hermitian [$J(-\theta)=J(\theta)^*$], periodic function of one variable $J(\theta)=J(\theta+2\pi)$ is positive semi-definite iff the Fourier components of $J(\theta)$ are non-negative, i.e.

> $1/2\pi\int\limits_0^{2\pi}J(\theta)e^{-il\theta}d\theta\geq0,\quad \forall \:l\in\mathbb{Z}.$

My question is how to extend this to a Hermitian [$W(\theta_1,\theta_2)=W(\theta_2,\theta_1)^*$], periodic function of two variables, $W(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. Does the following hold?

> $W(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ positive semi-definite iff $1/(2\pi)^2\iint\limits_0^{2\pi}e^{-il\theta_1}W(\theta_1,\theta_2)e^{im\theta_2}d\theta_1d\theta_2\geq0,\quad \forall \:l,m\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Edit: Thank you Ryszard Szwarc, for your answer. I don't understand all of the terminology used in your answer, though. Would someone be able to explain more explicitly what the terms in the theorem represent, and how they apply to the theorem above? It says on Wikipedia that the set $\mathbb{T}$ denotes the unit circle. I am confused about the following:

> What do you mean by dual group? I know that dual space is the space of linear mappings from V to our field. But why does our dual group $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and what is $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general [Bochner theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) theorem for locally compact abelian groups characterizing positive definite functions. For  compact abelian group $G$ it is as follows: the function $\varphi(g)$ is positive definite if and only if $\widehat{\varphi}(\gamma )\ge 0$ for any $\gamma \in \Gamma .$ The symbol $\Gamma$ denotes the dual group, i.e. the group of all homomorphisms from $G$ into the unit circle and $$\widehat{\varphi}(\gamma)=\int\limits_G \varphi(g)\overline{\gamma}(g)\,dg$$
In your case the group is $G=\mathbb{T}\times \mathbb{T},$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the complex unit circle, and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: This is the issue; I am not very familiar with this area of mathematics. What do you mean by dual group? I know that dual space is the space of linear mappings from V to our field. But why does our dual group $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and what is $\gamma$? What is the set $\mathbb{T}$? And just for confirmation, are you saying that the theorem I wrote is true? Thank you so much.

Comment: The dual group is the group of all characters on $G,$ i.e. continuous homomorphism from $G$ to $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, |z|=1\}.$ There  is a whole theory concerning topological groups, abelian in particular. I can recommend 
the textbook:  Rudin, W. (1990), Fourier analysis on groups, Wiley-Interscience,

Comment: Rudin is very difficult to read; I read baby Rudin, and got stuck on chapter 10. Is there a reference that will explain these terms quicker? thanks for your help.

Comment: You may try:  Loomis, L. H. (1953), An introduction to abstract harmonic analysis, Van Nostrand